# NodeClamError: No valid & active virus scanning binaries are active and available and no host/socket option provided

Tags: antivirus, clamav

I'm trying to use ClamScan to interact with a WSL 2 installation of ClamAV.
ClamAV is installed in `/usr/bin/clamscan` as indicated by the `which clamscan` command.

```
const clamScan = await new nodeClam().init({
    removeInfected: true,
    scanRecursively: true,
    clamscan: {
        path: "/usr/bin/clamscan",
        scanArchives: true,
        active: true
    },
    preference: "clamscan"
})
```

I get this error: `NodeClamError: No valid & active virus scanning binaries are active and available and no host/socket option provided!`

If it is of any importance the project is in `/mnt/d`